# What is the idiom for passing command line arguments to TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, command-line-arguments, gflags

[Previous versions](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.9/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py) of TensorFlow used `tf.app.flags` for command like flags:

```
flags = tf.app.flags
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS
flags.DEFINE_string('data_dir', '/tmp/data/', 'Directory for storing data')
```

but [recent versions](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py) now have just

```
import argparse
#...
FLAGS = None
```

wherever such code once appeared, importing `argparse` but not using it anywhere (that I can find).

The previous heavy use of `tf.app.flags` seemed like an endorsement of the [`gflags` architecture](https://github.com/google/python-gflags) as a kind of idiom for TensorFlow projects. Is it's removal an indication that another approach is now idiomatic and should be used in its place? If so, what approach, and is there a simple suggested migration path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a commit [`8018346`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/8018346e12f9fef76cdc7accc248de17514f6d38) of TF, the maintainer of TF, [vrv](https://github.com/vrv),  replied:

> Yup! tf.flags is something that is used within Google but has a bunch of problems, we suggest using argparse when possible.

As for the migration, you can checkout the same commit which did exactly the task.

Comment: Excellent; and too bad; the only reason I bothered learning `gflags` (as `tf.flags`) was because TensorFlow used them!